# Implementing a cold source with Mutiny

Tags: mutiny, backpressure

I'd like to know, what is a proper way to implement my own cold source (publisher) using the Mutiny library.

Let's say there is huge file parser that should return lines as `Multi<String>` items according to the Subscriber's consumption rate.
New lines should be read only after previous were processed to optimize memory usage, while buffering a couple of hundred items to eliminate consumer idling.

I know about the `Multi.createFrom.emitter()` factory method, but using it I can't see a convenient way to implement the backpressure.

Does Mutiny have a idiomatic way to create cold sources that produce next items only after requested by the downstream, or in this case I supposed to implement my own `Publisher` using the Java Reactive Streams API and then wrap it in `Multi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Multi.createFrom().generator(...)](https://javadoc.io/static/io.smallrye.reactive/mutiny/1.7.0/io/smallrye/mutiny/groups/MultiCreate.html#generator(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiFunction)).

The function is called for every request. But you can pass a "state" to remember where you are, typically an `Iterator`.

This is the opposite of the emitter approach (which does not check for requests but has a backpressure strategy attached to it).

If you need more fine-grain back-pressure support, you would need to implement a `Publisher`.